# ESRI AppRef Throws Com 8000FFFF error

Tags: c#, com, arcgis, esri

i am using the arcGIS api to make a plugin for arcFM, when i try to run this code

```
 Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriFramework.AppRef");
                System.Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                pApp = obj as IApplication;
```

i get

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException(0x8000FFFF): Creating an instance of the component with CLSID {Appref CLSID HERE} from the IClassFactory faileddue to the following error: 8000ffff
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was impossible i needed to be using arcMap not ArcFM

Answer (score 0):

In the [AppRef CoClass documentation](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/componenthelp/esriFramework/AppRef.htm), it says:

> Note you can only use the AppRef
>   object if your code is running inside
>   one of the ArcGIS application
>   processes.

Forum posts seem to confirm that this is the same error which is seen when this constraint has been violated:

From http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1729&t=217861:

> It is my understanding that there is
>   indeed no way to access the
>   IApplication instance from a
>   geoprocessing script.
>
> In theory, if your task is purely
>   geoprocessing, you should be able to
>   do it all without accessing the
>   IApplication object.

It looks like the OP of the above forum post was able to get around their problem by "using IToolboxWorkspace and accessing directely the Esri-toolboxes".  This was her code:

```
public IGPTool GetTool(string _sToolName, string _sToolboxName)
{
    IWorkspaceFactory pGPTFact;
    IToolboxWorkspace pToolboxWorkspace;
    IGPToolbox pGPToolbox;
    IGPTool pGPTool;

    pGPTFact = new ToolboxWorkspaceFactoryClass();

    pToolboxWorkspace =  pGPTFact.OpenFromFile(
        ArcGISInstallFolder + @"\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes", 0) as IToolboxWorkspace;
    pGPToolbox = pToolboxWorkspace.OpenToolbox(_sToolboxName); 
    pGPTool = pGPToolbox.OpenTool(_sToolName);
    return pGPTool;
}

private string ArcGISInstallFolder
{
    get
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.m_sArcGISInstallFolder))
        {
          Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regkey;
          regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
                                                 @"Software\ESRI\ArcGIS", false);
          this.m_sArcGISInstallFolder = regkey.GetValue("InstallDir") as String;
        }
        return this.m_sArcGISInstallFolder;
    }
}
```

Perhaps you can accomplish your goal either without the AppRef object or by running your script from inside the application.

Comment: You can... check out this example http://resources.arcfmsolution.com/DesktopSDK/CSharpMiscAttrAU.html